# Issue while invoking protoyped API in wso2 API store

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have installed apim 2.6.0 . I created a prototyped api  with inline implementation and uncommented the inline code.
But whenver we try to invoke the api in the api store , we are getting this unexpected response body. Tried  creating other api but the response is the same.

Response Body

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>WSO2 API Manager</title>

    <link href="../admin/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

    <link href="../styles/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link href="../dialog/css/jqueryui/jqueryui-themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          media="all"/>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admin/css/carbonFormStyles.css">
    <!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>        
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" href="../admin/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../admin/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/csrfPrevention.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dialog/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/WSRequest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/cookies.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/customControls.js"></script>
</head>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                if(getCookie('region1_configure_menu') == null){
if (window.location.protocol == "https:"){
  setCookie('region1_configure_menu', 'none','','','secure');
} else {  setCookie('region1_configure_menu', 'none');
}
}
if(getCookie('region3_registry_menu') == null){
if (window.location.protocol == "https:"){
  setCookie('region3_registry_menu', 'none','','','secure');
} else {  setCookie('region3_registry_menu', 'none');
}
}
if(getCookie('region4_monitor_menu') == null){
if (window.location.protocol == "https:"){
  setCookie('region4_monitor_menu', 'none','','','secure');
} else {  setCookie('region4_monitor_menu', 'none');
}
}
if(getCookie('region5_tools_menu') == null){
if (window.location.protocol == "https:"){
  setCookie('region5_tools_menu', 'none','','','secure');
} else {  setCookie('region5_tools_menu', 'none');
}
}

                                </script>

<body>
<noscript>
<div class="something-wrong">
                <div class="title">JavaScript is disabled on your browser</div>
                <div class="content">Please enable JavaScript or upgrade to a JavaScript-capable browser to use WSO2 Products.</div>
</div>
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<div class="something-wrong">
                <div class="title">Did you know that your Internet Explorer is out of date?</div>
                <div class="content">To get the best possible experience using our website we recommend that you upgrade to a newer version.</div>
</div>
<![endif]-->

<div id="dcontainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dialog/js/dialog.js"></script>

<!-- JS imports for collapsible menu -->
<script src="../yui/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/animation/animation-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../admin/js/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/selector/selector-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="main-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="header" colspan="3">
<!--[IF IE 7]>
                <style>
                                div#header-div div.right-links{
                                                position:absolute;
                                }
                </style>
<![endif]-->


    <div id="header-div">
        <div class="right-logo">Management Console</div>
        <div class="left-logo">
            <a href="../admin/index.jsp" class="header-home"><img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="300px" height="32px"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-ad">





        </div>
        <div class="header-links">
                                <div class="right-links">            
                                                <ul>

                                                <li class="right">
                                                    <a href="../admin/login.jsp">Sign-in</a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li class="middle">|</li>
                                                <li class="middle">
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation">Docs</a>
                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="middle">|</li>

                                                <li class="left">
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="../product/about.html">About</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="vertical-menu-container" id="vertical-menu-container" style="display:none;">
            <div id="menu-panel-button0"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button1" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button2" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button3" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button4" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button5" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button_dummy" style="display:none"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="menu-panel" valign="top">
            <table id="menu-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="region1">








        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"><li><a href="../admin/index.jsp" class="menu-home">Home</a></li><li id="region1_manage_menu" class="menu-header"  onclick="mainMenuCollapse(this.childNodes[0])" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="../admin/images/up-arrow.gif" class="mMenuHeaders" id="region1_manage_menu"/>Manage</li><li class="normal"><ul class="sub"></ul></li> </ul></div>


</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region2">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region3">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>

</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region4">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>

</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region5">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="225px" height="1px"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="middle-content">
            <table id="content-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="page-header-links">





                <table class="page-header-links-table" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                                <td class="breadcrumbs">
                                                <table class="breadcrumb-table" cellspacing="0">
                                                                <tr>                                                                                                                       
                                                                    <td>
                                                                                    <div id="breadcrumb-div"></div>
                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                </table>
                                                </td>

                                                <td class="page-header-help"><a href="./docs/userguide.html"
                                                                target="_blank">Help</a></td>

                                </tr>
                </table>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="body">
                        <img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="735px" height="1px"/>















<script type="text/javascript">
    var msgId;

    msgId = 'MSG15482962385250.12826686230343076';

</script>









     <script type="text/javascript">

        function doValidation() {
            var reason = "";

            var userNameEmpty = isEmpty("username");
            var passwordEmpty = isEmpty("password");

            if (userNameEmpty || passwordEmpty) {
                CARBON.showWarningDialog('Please enter a valid user name and a password.');
                document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

    </script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
                function getSafeText(text){
                                text = text.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
                                return text.replace(/>/g,'&gt');
                }

        function checkInputs(){
                var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
                var backendUrl = document.getElementById("txtbackendURL");
                var username = document.getElementById("txtUserName");

                backendUrl.value = getSafeText(backendUrl.value);
                username.value = getSafeText(username.value);
                loginForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <div id="middle">
        <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="features">
                        <table cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="feature feature-top">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation"><img src="../admin/images/user-guide.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation">User Guide</a></h3>

                                    <p>WSO2 Carbon user guide.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/forum/187"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/forum.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/forum/187">Forum</a>
                                    </h3>

                                    <p>The interactive message board for sharing information, questions and comments about WSO2 products.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank"
                                       href="https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/issue-tracker.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank"
                                           href="https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER">
                                        Issue Tracker</a></h3>

                                    <p>Users are encouraged to report issues & suggest improvements using the JIRA issue tracker. In addition, users can observe the status of the reported issues in progress.</p>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/mail"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/mailing-list.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/mail">
                                        Mailing Lists</a></h3>

                                    <p>Report issues, provide feedback & get help from our mailing lists.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                    <div id="loginbox">
                        <h2>Sign-in</h2>

                        <form action='../admin/login_action.jsp' method="POST" onsubmit="return doValidation();" target="_self" onsubmit="checkInputs()">
                            <table>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="txtUserName">Username</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="username"
                                               class="user" tabindex="1"  autocomplete="off" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password"
                                               class="password" tabindex="2"  autocomplete="off"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" 
                                                                                                value="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                        <label for="txtRememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Sign-in"
                                               class="button" tabindex="3"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <br/>
                                                            <a target="_blank" href="../docs/signin_userguide.html" tabindex="4">
                            Sign-in Help
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init(loginStatus) {
            // intialize the code and call to the back end
            /*wso2.wsf.Util.initURLs();*/
            /*Initialize the XSLT cache*/
            /*wso2.wsf.XSLTHelper.init();*/

            if (loginStatus == 'true') {
            } else if (loginStatus == 'null') {
            } else if (loginStatus == 'false') {
                wso2.wsf.Util.alertWarning("Login failed. Please recheck the user name and password and try again")
            } 
        }
        document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
    </script>



                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="footer" colspan="3">

<div id="footer-div">
                <div class="footer-content">
                                <div class="copyright">
                                    &copy; 2005 - 2018 WSO2 Inc. All Rights Reserved.
                                </div>
                                <!--div class="poweredby">
                                </div-->
                </div>
</div>

</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
    document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

response header returned is

> cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private  content-encoding: gzip  content-language: en-US  content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8  date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 02:17:18 GMT  expires: 0  pragma: no-cache  server: WSO2 Carbon Server  status: 200  vary: Accept-Encoding  x-content-type-options: nosniff  x-frame-options: DENY  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

even though the response content type is application/json

Comment: Have you uncommented the whole inline code?

Comment: yes.. even for a managed endpoint unlike prototyped endpoint , getting the same default wso2 html as response body

Comment: anyone has any inputs or has faced this issue before as I can't get much from the logs